# sonata installation on windows xampp

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, sonata

i want to install sonata on windows 8 xampp.

I use comand php composer.phar create-project sonata-project/sandbox:2.3.x-dev and after download I get error. I found that error is for me 2 lines:

in bin\load.data.php

1. `rm -rf ./app/cache/*`

   I can comment that
2. `-d memory_limit=1024M -d max_execution_time=600 ./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --verbose --env=dev --no-debug`

   If I increase memory limit to 1024m and time to 600 in `php.ini` and remove that part, I still get this error:

   ```
   Executing : C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\xampp\php\php.exe ./app/console doctrine:fix
   tures:load --verbose --env=dev --no-debug
   Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue Y/N ?

   [RuntimeException]
   Aborted

   Exception trace:
   () at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony
   \src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper.php:115
   Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper->ask() at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\
   xampp\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console
   \Helper\DialogHelper.php:242
   Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper->askConfirmation() at C:\Users\Fe
   lek\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-fixtures-bundle
   \Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php:73
   Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand->execute
   () at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\
   src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:252
   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\xamp
   p\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\App
   lication.php:896
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop
   \xampp\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Consol
   e\Application.php:193
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\xampp\
   htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\
   Console\Application.php:96
   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Users\Felek\D
   esktop\xampp\htdocs\sonata\sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\
   Console\Application.php:124
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\Users\Felek\Desktop\xampp\ht
   docs\sonata\sandbox\app\console:34

   doctrine:fixtures:load [--fixtures[="..."]] [--append] [--em="..."] [--purge-wit
   h-truncate]

   An error occurs when running a command!
   ```

   I tried to remove and install database again without any result. What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Answering the question that's asked you on the command line solves the problem...

Comment: The problem is i cant run that command when i load script.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. First I opened the script and change a line:

```
$bin . '  -d memory_limit=1024M -d max_execution_time=600 ./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --verbose -env=dev --no-debug',
```

to:

```
$bin . '  -d memory_limit=1024M -d max_execution_time=600 ./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --verbose --no-interaction --env=dev --no-debug',
```

Adding **--no-interaction** fixed the problem.

I also tried running

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M -d max_execution_time=600 ./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --verbose -env=dev --no-debug
```

in the console first and I got some errors then with a hint about missing fileinfo extension. It doesn't have to be always the case but worth checking.

I had to uncomment **extension=php_fileinfo.dll** in my php.ini file. ( the one which is in the same folder as your php.exe, not the apache one).